# Turtlebot navigation through narrow passageway

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, 2dcostmap, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Im trying to get my turtlebot to navigate its way through a pretty narrow path of about 48cm wide. I tried to solve the problem by adjusting the inflation radius of all the parameters (costmap_common_params, global_costmap_params, local_costmap_params) but to no avail. The picture in the link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xiy0w8xkq5migtq/ss2.png?dl=0) shows the error that I get when assign a 2D Nav goal to make the turtlebot go through the narrow passageway. The turtlebot also goes into recovery action followed by the  "DWA planner failed to produce path" message and "Aborting because a valid plan could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors" message. I am using an RPLidar A2 sensor only.

current parameter settings:

costmap_common_params:- robot_radius: 0.20, inflation_radius: 0.25;

local_costmap_params:- inflation_radius: 0.20;

global_costmap_params:- inflation_radius: 0.25

Is there a rule of thumb for setting the costmap parameters for such a case or are there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253537/turtlebot-navigation-through-narrow-passageway/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrozenCh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29243/frozench/) on 2017-02-02**:
try to shrink the inflation_radius in local cost map, or make the foot print smaller.

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-03**:
Thank you! The results have improved slightly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to find a good combination of parameters to allow the robot to maneuver through narrow passageways. This can be done not just through tweaking the inflation radius and robot footprint but also by manipulating other parameters like the neutral cost etc.

Managed to find a good [report](http://www.zkytony.com/documents/navguide.pdf) on setting the navigational parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) with karma: 62 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tilyevsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/36462/tilyevsky/) on 2018-12-20**:
The link is dead. Can you provide a new one? I am interested in navigating a robot through narrow passageways as well.

**Comment by [Drik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40722/drik/) on 2019-04-08**:
I am interested two!

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2019-04-09**:
You can reference this file. This was the file i used when figuring out how to overcome this problem. http://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-08-28**:
Hey @Rayner, so what were your parameters which worked? Could you please share them?